# Super weird multimeter behavior, multimeter is jump starting circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, multimeter, troubleshooting

So I have a custom PCB for a project that has an output port for a pump. The pump is rated for 8-24 VDC, 3-35 W, .3-1.5 A. The starting voltage is 9-13.2 VDC. The PCB is powered by a 24V power supply. When the power supply is turned on, the program is supposed to allow the pump to turn on. The software should be correct. However, when the power supply is turned on and the pump is supposed to turn on, nothing happens. With no load, I can measure 24V across the output port intended for the pump. When the pump is plugged in, the voltage jumps between 2-6V. (I'm assuming the board cannot provide enough current? Or is it voltage?)

When I plug the pump in with a multimeter in series on the negative side to measure current, I get about 150mA or less. I know the multimeter is plugged in correctly. I have the positive attached to the negative terminal of the pump and the negative of the multimeter attached to the negative terminal of the output port.

Here's where things get weird.

The multimeter is in 1A DC mode, but when switched to mA DC range, the current climbs and steadies around .740 A and the pump starts and stays on and reads 24V Across the pump. When I switch the multimeter back to 1A mode the pump remains on. The multimeter is essentially kick-starting the pump.

I think the pump not starting could be a hardware issue or a circuit design issue with the PCB, but does anyone know what is happening with the kick starting of the pump? I'm using a Meterman 15XP multimeter to measure current.

I'm a junior engineering student so my understanding of EE is still young. Please let me know if anyone has any ideas as to what is going on or if I need to provide anymore details.

Comment: I think your guess is correct: the pump is drawing too much current at startup (~3x normal running current) and is tripping some sort of overcurrent protection in your power supply.  The multimeter in mA mode is acting as an inrush current limiter which lowers this starting surge.  In high current mode, there is a different shunt resistor which is apparently too small to have the same effect.  I just measured the resistance between the mA terminal and COM of a meter I have and got ~700k ohms so I doubt there's a plain shunt resistor in there.  Someone with more knowledge can chip in on this.

Comment: @vir, ~700k ohms on a current shunt means your fuse is blown. Any digital meters I've seen will have a shut generate enough voltage for the meter module's full scale reading. The basic '199.9 mV' type need to generate 200 mV for full scale reading on each range so I would expect a 0.1 \$\Omega\$ shunt on the 2 A range and 0.01 \$\Omega\$ on the 10 A range. I think you're correct about the shunt being an inrush current limiter somehow.

Comment: Right you are, blown fuse.  My thought was maybe some sort of active circuitry on there but since it's a cheap Harbor Freight meter, this seems laughable in retrospect.  I tested meters the other way around and found ~3 ohms on the mA side (BK Precision 2703B).